# HM-10 as BLE Listener: setting up a brief connection from it

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I need to estabilish a brief communication between a BLE master and a BLE peripherical device.

Until I have to use the mobile phone I have no problems, since I select the bluetooth device from Android, I can connect to it and then I can receive data simply writing them to HM-10.

BUT, this approach is battery expensive, since the BLE scanning is more battery expensive than the BLE advertising (right?). So I want that the mobile becames an advertisor and the HM-10 takes the ROLE of Slave.

BUT, I still don't understand if it is possible to connect to other devices: I tried AT+CONN and it always fails (AT+CONF). Is there any way to send brief data from the HM-10  to the advertisor, even without connecting?

Even my firmware looks slightly different from the readme! For example,AT+LN is present in the documentation but it appears to not exist. Does a better version of the firmware for this device exist, or, are sources available somewhere? I installed the HM-Soft V705 (lastest).

Thanks

**UPDATE 1:**

@ChrisStratton Ok, I have some intresting news: I was already following your idea (phone advertise sometimes, while HM-10 always scan and tries to connect to the service if it sees it, then HM-10 send some data, phone answer). I managed to make the phone visible from HM-10 (don't ask me how!). I am using the BLE Tool Android app to test everything. Now, the central problem now is that HM-10 won't connect to the android service even if the advertisor is connectable (see attached images).

I am sospicious that the AT+CO (that I discovered is a kind a replacement of AT+LN, but I am not sure) can help, but i don't know how.

[image: AT Command Results]

[image: Gatt Server Advertisor]

[image: HM-10 Manual V609/V705]

Comment: Additional info: I mentioned AT+LN because it is the command explained here, where somebody seems to have wanted to do the same thing:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323071/send-custom-gatt-characteristics-using-hm-10-actually-a-cc2541.

Comment: "So I want that the mobile becames an advertisor and the HM-10 takes the ROLE of Slave." Unfortunately that is not how BLE works.  Peripherals advertise, Centrals receive advertisement.  You may be able to make the CC254x chip in the HM-10 function as a central, receive advertisements from the phone, and connect in response, but that would only make sense if your HM-10 has mains power, and I don't know if that capability of the underlying chip CC254x is supported by the HM-10 firmware.  Start by seeing if the firmware has any support for being a Central rather than a Peripheral.

Comment: Realistically, it's unclear that your plan here will result in substantial power savings - although scanning might (?) cost more than advertising for the same amount of time, you don't need to scan for very long, because you can stop when you find something.  And your plan is going to be a lot more complicated than doing things the usual way for which you presumably have guidance / examples.

Comment: I don't get it. Yes scanning consumes way more energy than advertising since the radio is on much more. "So I want that the mobile becames an advertisor and the HM-10 takes the ROLE of Slave." the slave role and the advertiser is the same device (slave is always an advertiser before connection is made).